# In react I Have displayed Bunch of items using map. On onclick function every item gets effected .I want only one who was clicked to change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

My problem is like so I have displayed bunch of items using map function. and render them conditionally as shown. I am using styled components this is the restriction for this project.
Now when I click on item I want to change it's border-color which must remain before I click on another item in same list. I know that I have to use useState But when I do that It updates every items in that list. In reality I want to change the color of only one item.

```
    <div className="specs-container">
            {specification.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  className="single-spec"
                  key={index}
                  id={item}
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: `${item}`, // some item has color name
                    color: `${item}` === "Black" ? "white" : "", // if item's color === black render white
                    fontSize: `${id === "Capacity"}` ? "0.7rem" : "20px",// based on category
                    border: `1px solid ${bgcolor} `, // here I have stucked
                  }}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                  // this is the problem
                    console.log(e.target.id);
                    let item = specification.filter((item) => item === e.target.id);

                    console.log(item);
                    
                    // if (e.target.id === item[0]) {
                    //   setBgcolor("green");
                    // }
                  }}
                >
                  {id === "Capacity" ||
                  id === "Size" ||
                  id === "With USB 3 ports" ||
                  id === "Touch ID in keyboard"
                    ? `${item}` // display item if conditionally
                    : ""}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </SpecWrapper>
```

[image]

Comment: `setBgcolor("green")` means you have a single string variable in your state. You need an array instead. You can also compute the background color while mapping over the items. Like `border: \`1px solid ${some_condition ? "green" : "transparent"}\``

Comment: That's right. Try doing it with a state with an array in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just store the index of the selected item in the state and compare that to the index in the map to change the background color

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
...
...
 <div
   className="single-spec"
   key={index}
   id={item}
   style={{
     backgroundColor: {selected===index ? 'green' : `${item}`, // some item has color name
     color: `${item}` === "Black" ? "white" : "", // if item's color === black render white
     fontSize: `${id === "Capacity"}` ? "0.7rem" : "20px",// based on category
     border: `1px solid ${bgcolor} `, // here I have stucked
              }}
  onClick={()=>setSelected(index)}
>
```